# How do I take a segment of a image and check if it exists?

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-ide

In Sikuli I have an image where I need to check if the 1/4 of the lower half exists and if it does, use a specific function. Right now I have:

```
if(image.exists())
click()
```

The issue with this though is the .exists will either hang the script or function incorrectly. I'm looking for a better way to do this or a solution to this problem. Any help would be appreciated
[image]
[image]

Example is there's an additional segment, so you have Select All in one version (where it ends) and then Time/Date in a newer version. Want to be able to select the additional option of Time/Date but through images.

Comment: @JimGrigoryan hopefully this helps? It's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

**This should be what you are looking for:**

```
noteApp = App("notepad.exe")
click("editbutton-1.png")
region = Region(noteApp.focusedWindow())
print(region.text())
```

You can set the region.text() equal to the string you are looking for such as Date/Time and create a statement to run your function

Comment: Works in some cases but due to 1.1.4 having text recognition issues with small text, this can't be a definitive answer. Still need something that would be able to recognize small text/image patterns.